# TailwindCSS: How to add a custom font?

Tags: tailwind-css

How do I add custom fonts to my React project? I see multiple examples but the nuances make it not work currently.

I'm trying to add this custom font (Google font) called [LodrinaSolid](https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Londrina+Solid).

In my index.css I add all the weights, but not sure

1. Should it be `format("ttf")` or `format("truetype")` as per [this](https://github.com/tailwindlabs/tailwindcss/discussions/2060#discussioncomment-1037915) or do I need to even include it?
2. Where should the fonts folder be? In the `public` folder outside of the src, or can it be inside src? I assume outside the src folder and in the `public` folder. I currently have it in a fonts folder. And I assume url("fonts/LondrinaSolid-Black.ttf") links to the public folder.
3. Do all the @font-face's need to be wrapped in a @layer object?

```css
@font-face {
    font-family: "londrinaBlack";
    font-weight: 900;
    src: url("fonts/LondrinaSolid-Black.ttf") format("truetype");
}
@font-face {
    font-family: "londrinaLight";
    font-weight: 300;
    src: url("fonts/LondrinaSolid-Light.ttf") format("truetype");
}
@font-face {
    font-family: "londrinaRegular";
    font-weight: 400;
    src: url("fonts/LondrinaSolid-Regular.ttf");
}
@font-face {
    font-family: "londrinaThin";
    font-weight: 100;
    src: url("fonts/LondrinaSolid-Thin.ttf");
}
```

My tailwind.config.js

1. Because the fonts aren't even loading in index.css, I tried loading it with a script tag in `public>index.html` and I'm not sure if loading it here should be written as '"Londrina+Solid"', or '"Londrina Solid"'
2. Otherwise, should I be adding all the weights I loaded in `indexcss` here or somewhere else?

```js
module.exports = {
    darkMode: "class",
    content: ["./src/**/*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}"],
    theme: {
        extend: {
            fontFamily: {
                londrina: [
                    "londrinaRegular",
                    "londrinaThin",
                    "londrinaBlack",
                    "londrinaRegular",
                    // '"Londrina+Solid"',
                    "sans-serif",
                ],
            },
        },
    },
    plugins: [],
};
```

Comment: I usually add the fonts in the `src` directory and then have a `fonts.css` file which is then imported into something like `app.css`. Also, you don't need to add the font weights in the `londrina` array. You can do `londrina: ['londrinaRegular', 'sans-serif']` and then write classes like `font-londrina font-black`.

Comment: @markmead Thanks for the  heads up. I got it to work. I also realized the font-family is the same name. Also got help from [this link](https://hamidafghan.me/blog/tailwind-css-add-fonts-form-your-local) to clarify the nuances. Wanna post an answer?

Comment: @markmead Let me know if you wanna post an answer for my to accept, friend!

Comment: Great to hear it worked! I've copied my comment as an answer.

Answer (score 2):

**Answer from comments**

I usually add the fonts in the src directory and then have a fonts.css file which is then imported into something like app.css. Also, you don't need to add the font weights in the `londrina` array. You can do `londrina: ['londrinaRegular', 'sans-serif']` and then write classes like font-londrina font-black.